# Let $f(x) = w_1 x_1 + w_2 x_2$, does $\dfrac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}$ produce a column vector or a row vector?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, notation, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

Suppose that $f(x) = w_1 x_1 + w_2 x_2 = w \cdot x$,

where $w = [w_1, x_2], x = \begin{bmatrix} x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}$

Does
 $\dfrac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}$

produce a column vector or a row vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's really no difference between a column and a row vector.  They're two different ways of writing the same thing.

Furthermore, what's $\partial f/\partial x$?

For a linear map, it can always be represented by a matrix, and the "derivative" turns out to be the same map.

Comment: In literature I've seen, $\partial/\partial \boldsymbol{x}$ where $\boldsymbol{x}$ is a vector is understood to be the derivative of the entire vector i.e using the example above $\partial(\boldsymbol{w} \cdot \boldsymbol{x})/d \boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{w} \cdot \boldsymbol{e}$ where $\boldsymbol{e}$ is a vector of ones.